# Unsure about bleeds with die cut

Tags: print-design, print-production, bleed, diecut

I have this design (viewed here at 600%) that is going to be cut to the shape of the red outline (cut line only - not part of the design)

[image]

I'm pretty sure my bleeds are good everywhere EXCEPT where the white outline from the pig intersects with the light yellow outline from the rounded rectangle making up the lower half... specifically:

here...
[image]

and here...
[image]

It seems to me that however I slice it, I run the risk of either having some yellow where it should be white or vice versa.

Is there a standard way of handling this to get the best results?

Comment: erring on the side of white is probably better so id offset the white instead of yellow or split the difference. but yeah theres no good unversal way of handling this.

Comment: Dealing with misregistration is always a matter of compromising. This might be not such a bad option. An alternative would that the yellow-white edge of the bleed would follow the medial axis between the white edge and yellow edge.

Comment: This is related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/131662/84899

Comment: Op should be attentive to the drop shadow: it appears they are clipping it, which might be worse than a misregistration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, **speak to the production house**. Ask them how they would prefer matters like this to be handled. They have the experience with their machines. They may have a specific method for just this scenario.

---

I would handle this by running the white at a 45° angle starting from the point the white and yellow meet...

[image]

Bleed colors don't have to be straight, perpendicular, fields of color. By making the white/yellow joint a 45° angle outward, you eliminate the possibility of yellow appearing around the white edge.

Everything is a compromise really.

This *would* increase the possibility of a sliver of white appearing in the yellow area right where the two meet. For my money, that would be the lesser of the two evils (a tiny white speck in the yellow at the joint as opposed to a yellow rim around the white area.)

Answer (score 0):

Scott is right, angle of 45 is the best solution.
But if it is really a 600% mag (~65x41.6 mm), I think the cut margin or lack of it is more concerning... (not to mention the sub optimal cutting angles and edges)